# Displaying Group Name with Group Members

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am trying to solve an assignment in my Java class. I am stuck and need a little help. 
I am trying to create a method in my Group class that will display the group name and the 4 students in the group. My code currently displays the group name and the memory location of my student inside my array.

```
public class Group {
/**-------Declaring attributes----*/
String groupName;
int newStudentCount;

/**----------------------------*/

/**--------Constructor------------*/
public Group(String givenGroupName) {
    groupName = givenGroupName;
}

Student[] students = new Student[4];

/**----------------------------*/

/**--------Method------------*/
void addStudent(Student st) {
    students[newStudentCount] = st;
    ++newStudentCount;
    System.out.println("New student: " +st.getName());
 }
 public String getGroup() {
   return "Group = " + groupName;
}
public Student getStudent(){
    return students[0];
}
```

}

In my App class I have this:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Group g1 = new Group("Pink Pony Princesses");
    Student st1 = new Student("Joshua Mathews");
    st1.getName();
    g1.addStudent(st1);

    Student st2 = new Student("Jame Brooks");
    g1.addStudent(st2);

    Student st3 = new Student("Mike Myers");
    g1.addStudent(st3);

    Student st4 = new Student("Christie Richie");
    g1.addStudent(st4);

    System.out.println(g1.getGroup()+ " " + g1.getStudent());
```

}

This is my Student class:

```
public class Student {
/**-------Declaring attributes----*/
String name;
String degree;
int age;


/**----------------------------*/

/**--------Constructor------------*/
Student(String givenName){
    name = givenName;
}
Student(String givenName,  String givenDegree, int givenAge) {
    name = givenName;
    degree = givenDegree;
    age = givenAge;

}


/**--------- METHODS --------*/
//Array
public final String [] activities = {
        "Working on Homework", "Playing a Game", "Taking a Nap"
};

String getInfo(){
    return name + age + degree;
}
String getName() {
    return name;
}
int getAge(){
    return age;
}
String getDegree() {
    return degree;
}

String whatsUp(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(activities.length);
    String returnActivity = activities[randomIndex];
    return returnActivity;
}
```

I'm not sure how to call my array to display the 4 names, and not the memory location of them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your student class looks like

Comment: nevermind, i'll go without it

Comment: I added it, sorry just had to edit my post.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I can deduce a couple of things from your question.

First, you are returning only the student at index 0 of the `Student` array held within your `Group` object. If you want to return all students your method signature should have a `Student[]` as the return type rather than a `Student` object.

If you follow the above prompt then you will have to iterate through the returned array printing each Student object.

Regardless of which implementation you choose the reason you print out a memory reference rather than a String object is that you have not overridden `toString` within your Student class.

Something like this will print out Student data when passed to a `System.out` call:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return someStudentData;
}
```

Comment: I have the index set to 0 to test the code and see what it would return. When I followed your first suggestion of using
    return Student[];
I got an error.

Comment: Because you need to actually return the array of Students. Just change your return to `return students` instead of `return students[0]`

Comment: this is the error I get: Error:(30, 16) java: incompatible types: Student[] cannot be converted to Student

Comment: That's because you need to actually handle the return type of Student[] and assign it to a declaration of a Student[], then iterate through printing out each student.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with what andrewdleach said by implementing toString(). OR
To print all student names your method should be something like:

```
public String getStudent(){

  String studentNames = "";
  for(Student stu: students){
    studentNames+= stu.getName() + ",";
  }

  return studentNames;
}
```